# cargar un archivo HTML (que tiene tambien funciones JS) en otro archivo desde un evento Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

lo que quiero hacer y estoy algo confundido, es separar en archivos elementos HTML que tienen eventos y funciones propias y poder cargarlo en un nuevo archivo cuando el usuario realice un clic.

por ejemplo tengo un archivo solo con este codigo:

formulario1.html:

```
<div>
    <form id="form1">
        <input type="number" id="number1">
        <button id="btn1" onclick="f1()" >calcular</button>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    function f1(){
        let cadena="usuario"+document.getElementById("numnber1") ;
        return cadena;
    }
</script>
```

y desde otro archivo quiero que se inserte todo su contenido y las funciones que tenga en otro contenedor de otra pagina:
archivo: editor.html:

```
<html><head><body>...
    <div>
            <button id="btnCargar1" onclick="cargar('formulario1.html')">Cargar Formulario</button>
            <button id="btnCargar2" onclick="cargar('tabla1.html')">Cargar tabla</button>
            <button id="btnCargar3" onclick="cargar('imagenes1.html')">Cargar imagen</button>
            <div id="contenedor1"></div>
    </div>
        <script>
            function cargar(archivo){
                let contenedor= document.getElementById("contenedor1");
                contenedor.innerHTML=""; //limpio
                contenedor.innerHTML= //contenido del archivo formulario1.html
            }
        </script>
```

Con php logro que se visualice por medio de "include", pero en este caso necesito hacerlo con javascript y lo que he podido ver con el import de JS es que traigo las funciones pero no el html, cualquier recomendación me serviria :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar la [API fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) para obtener el nuevo contenido por AJAX, sin embargo, eso no garantiza que las etiquetas `<script>` sean interpretadas.

```
function cargar(archivo) {
    // Ejecutar petición para cargar el archivo
    fetch(archivo)
        // Al obtener respuesta del servidor, tomar el texto o html
        .then(res => res.text())
        // Si se interpretó correctamente, el contenido está en la variable html
        .then(html => {
            // Obtener contenedor
            let contenedor = document.getElementById("contenedor1");
            // Asignar nuevo contenido
            contenedor.innerHTML = html;
         })
         // Si algo falló, mostrar mensaje en consola
         .catch(e => {
             console.log('Error importando archivo: ' + e.message);
         });
}
```

Si los scripts del archivo importando no funcionan, tal vez debas interpretar el nuevo html con [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) e insertar cada nodo con [.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

**Importante:** DOMParser aún está en etapa experimental y podría no funcionar como se espera, por lo que te recomiendo verificar [soporte disponible en los diferentes navegadores](https://caniuse.com/?search=DOMParser)

Answer (score 2):

Lo podrías solucionar con el uso de iframes

la etiqueta
`<div id="contenedor1"></div>` deberás cambiarla por `<iframe id="contenedor1"></iframe>`

y en tu función de js **cargar()** deberás pasar la url del archivo que deseas que aparezca, y con el metodo setAttribute cambiarás el valor del atributo src

por ejemplo

```
function cargar(archivo){
   let contenedor= document.getElementById("contenedor1");
   contenedor.setAttribute('src',archivo)
}
```